# STM8 Development Board with Arduino IDE

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, c++

I got one of these cheap STM8 boards from China and was hoping to find a way to use this with arduino code. 
[image: STM8 development board]
Does anyone know of an arduino boot loader and board package that works with them ?

Comment: you get nothing with these links !!!!

Answer (score 2):

Start the Arduino-IDE. In File->Preferences, Settings tab, enter

https://github.com/tenbaht/sduino/raw/master/package_sduino_stm8_index.json

Open Tools->Board:...->Boards Manager

Find Sduino by typing 'sd' into the search line

Click on the list entry

Click on Install.

This link is more comprehensive

https://tenbaht.github.io/sduino/

Answer (score 1):

There is a bootloader on those chips to slow serial programming. A much easier way to to get a stlink debugger.

There are also some packages that allow Arduino styled programming on those chips. I wrote one myself that runs on iar and I think at least one on sdcc.

Those chips are really nice.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. So how would I get started with programming this in the arduino IDE? There is a whole community around the STM32 and it's use with the arduino IDE, I followed some simple instructions from stm32duino.com to get going with the stm32. Is there an equivalent with this STM8 board?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, unfortunately. The stm32duino site has links to my stm8duino port on GitHub if you wish to try. It does require the iar workbench however .